# Deadlock in queries

Tags: mysql

I get this exception:

Error Code : 1213
Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction

I am running 3 delete statements and 1 update statement in a query window. When i run those queries it throws error code 1213 and deadlock exception.

My mysql version is 5.0. Please share your views.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you share your queries and the output of SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS. That way we can help you better.

Answer (score 0):

A single transaction cannot cause a deadlock.  I'm not sure what you mean by a "query window", but if you are running all of those statements on a single connection/transaction, then there is something else that is holding the locks that your statements need.

[SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-monitors.html) can show you what locks are being held by different connections.